# Laravel Store Array in Session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been having trouble storing an array in session. I am making a shopping cart and it doesn't seem to work.

```
public function __construct(){

  $product = array(1,2,3,4);
  Session::push('cart', $product);

}
```

and then retrieve it in the view like this.

```
{{Session::get('cart')}}
```

However I keep getting an error like this.

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Any clues and advice on how to create a shopping cart that stores an array of items.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you need to use the array from session as a string, you need to use Collection like this:

```
$product = collect([1,2,3,4]);
Session::push('cart', $product);
```

This will make it work when you will be using `{{Session::get('cart');}}` in your htmls. Be aware of `Session::push` because it will append always the new products in sessions. You should be using `Session::put` to be sure the products will be always updating.

Answer (score 8):

You're storing an array in the session, and since `{{ }}` expects a string, you can't use `{{Session::get('cart')}}` to display the value.

The `{{ $var }}` is the same as writing `echo htmlentities($var)` (a very simple example).

Instead, you could do something like:

```
@foreach (Session::get('cart') as $product_id)
    {{$product_id}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I was curious why does collections or $request->all() can be used through {{ }} ? Don't htmlentities goes through them too?

Comment: @Nello Collections provides a wrapper for working with arrays. If you attempt to `echo $collection` or use `{{ $collection }}`, the Collection handles this automatically using a [`__toString()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L1138-L1146) method. The `$request->all()` would be handled as a Collection, rather than a normal array.

Answer (score 5):

If you use 'push', when initially creating the array in the session, then the array will look like this:

```
[
    0 => [1,2,3,4]
]
```

Instead you should use 'put':

```
$products = [1,2,3,4];
$request->session()->put('cart', $products);
```

Any subsequent values should be pushed onto the session array:

```
$request->session()->push('cart', 5);
```

Comment: Absolutely right, thanks for spotting. I've corrected the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.`:

```
$product = array(1,2,3,4);
Session::put('cart.product',$product);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array in session like
    `$cart = session('data', []);`

```
$cart[] = $product;

session([ 'data' => $cart]);

return session('data', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it like that:

```
  $data = collect($Array); 
  Session()->put('data', $data);
  return view('pagename');
```