# Looking for some helps in adding policy to my laravel projects

Tags: laravel

I am new in learning laravel. Currently I have been stuck in the Laravel Policy,could you please kindly help with directing me how to add policy to my project?

I would like to make just only the Administrator User be able to see the 'Administration Dashboard' by using Laravel Policies Rules but failed. Actually every registered user is able to see that entrance(just like the attached picture showing below).

The user name is uu@gmail.com and the password is uuuuuu. 
Please go to my testing website http://lookoko.com/ and log with the user name and password you will see that Administration Dashboard list in the drop-down lists.

[image]

Comment: Show your code for policies or I would suggest you use Laravel middleware for this purpose https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

Comment: I've read the laravel documentation for two days and still can not finished that.So I have to ask helps from this community. Thank you so much for your understanding.Thank you

Comment: @Amit Gupta  yes, I've tried the Laravel middleware and succeeded but now I would like to learn how to use policy so I hope could achieve that goal by adding policy to it.Please allow me to ask that could you please help adding policy to my project? I build this website and make it open source because I would like to help the newbie like me to reduce the learning curves in the learning process and have more time and space to learn more and more.Thank you

Comment: Then I would recommend you to read the docs for the policy and it you are stuck anywhere we may help you in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new middleware, use the `make:middleware` Artisan command:

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware
```

This command will place a new `AdminMiddleware` class within your `app/Http/Middleware` directory. In this middleware, we will only allow access to the route if the logged-in user is admin. Otherwise, we will redirect the users back to the `home` URI.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! auth()->user()->is_admin) {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

*Here I am assumming you have a column in user table named `is_admin`*

**Registering Middleware**

You should assign the middleware a key in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file. By default, the `$routeMiddleware` property of this class contains entries for the middleware included with Laravel. To add your own, simply append it to this list and assign it a key of your choosing. For example:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    ...
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
];
```

Once the middleware has been defined in the HTTP kernel, you may use the `group` method to assign middleware to group of routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
    // all your admin routes comes here
});
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Amit. Your answer is very detailed for me.Could you please figure out how to implement how to add policy to it in detail?Because now I hope could master how to use the Laravel policy. I've learned from the Laravel 5.2 documentation that with the can method in the View can also achieve this goal but I tried many times still not succeeded.