# Laravel 5.6 - Grab message from Controller into view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm starting with Laravel and i need to show the output of a post request into the view. My controller file returns an array with a message, like this:

```
return redirect('/myroute')
            ->with('message', [
                'type' => 'success', 
                'text' => 'It works'
            ]);
```

In my view file, i'm trying to grab the message text, but no success. See my code below

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    {{ $msg = Session::get('message') }}
    <h4>{{ $msg->text }}</h4>
@endif
```

The point is: The condition works, if i changed the {{$msg->text}} to any text it works, but when i try to get the message text, it returns an error:

**htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

So, any help is apreciated. If more information is needed, just ask.

PS: i checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838978/laravel-redirect-back-with-message), but no success at all
EDITED:
PS2: Can't change controller structure

Comment: Have you checked what `$msg` exactly contains? Try dumping it in the controller to see whether it is an array, an object, a string,......

Comment: @NicoHaase i tried to dump it {{var_dump($msg)}} inside template but still got the same error

Answer (score 4):

Try accessing the array as follows:

```
<h4>{{ $msg['text'] }}</h4>
```

or just pass an array with the items

```
->with([
            'type' => 'success', 
            'text' => 'It works'
        ]);

//in the view
@if(session()->has('text'))
    <h4> {{ session('text') }} </h4>
@endif
```

-- EDIT

iterate than over the session like so:

```
@foreach (Session::get('message') as $msg)
  {{$msg['text']}}
@endforeach
```

you can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338526/laravel-store-array-in-session)

Comment: It didn't wok for me, same error. Can't change controller structure. I tried also {{$msg->text}} and error persist.

Comment: Then you have to iterate over the session in order to access your items. Look at my Edit above

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still not working, Error message now is 'Illegal string offset 'text''

Comment: try to `var_dump` the content of the `$msg` within the view and see what it has, something is missing there so I cannot debug it when I don't have the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

```
return redirect('/myroute')->with('success','It worked');
```

Then on your view

```
{{session('success')}}
```

Comment: Unfornunatelly i can't change controller structure