# create shopping cart - laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create my own shopping cart

I would like to know what is the way to store various items and then show the items in the cart

```
public function __construct()
{
    if(!\Session::has('cart')) \Session::put('cart', array());
}
```

my question is what code do I use to show the cart and then insert items inside it

Comment: Have a shopping cart array saved in a session. Each time user adds, add to the array and save in session. When you need to fetch everything, grab the array from the session

Comment: Take a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37338994/6908226

Answer (score 0):

While this is **not a strictly Laravel solution**, it is a relatively simple and well supported (browser compatible) way to store simple session data on the client side. I do this using sessionStorage. Take a look at the sessionStorage documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Example JS:

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('cart', 'item_id');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
let data = sessionStorage.getItem('cart');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('cart');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

A shopping cart would usually store several different items and while sessionStorage does not store arrays, the workaround is to convert the comma seperated string to an array using `split(",")`.

Example:

```
//if cart has value of 11,12,13,14,15
var ex1 = sessionStorage.getItem('cart').split(',');
//ex1 would be [11,12,13,14,15]

//without split(',')
var ex2 = sessionStorage.getItem('cart');
//ex2 would be 11,12,13,14,15
```